# Adding x amount of days to a start date but excluding holidays?

Tags: excel

I'd like to add x amount of days to a start date, but excluding certain holidays so they are not included in the days apart.

For instance I have a start date of 1/1/2020 and would like to add 75 days from that date, but for the holiday of 1/18/2020 I want it to not include this day in the calculation because it is a holiday. I know there is the Workday formula which excludes holidays and adds business days only but I want to add all days including weekends. What formula would accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you want to **include** weekends and working days and only exclude holidays??

Comment: Correct @Gary'sStudent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`WORKDAY.INTL()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/workday-intl-function-a378391c-9ba7-4678-8a39-39611a9bf81d)

```
=WORKDAY.INTL("1/1/2020",75,"0000000","1/18/2020")
```

the holidays can also be a range:

```
=WORKDAY.INTL("1/1/2020",75,"0000000",B1:B20)
```

Comment: Cool - didn't know you could use the string "0000000" like that.

Comment: Thank you Scott, ill try this out now

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! Along with everyone else who commented